# Malformed url when switching form app engine SDK to Google cloud SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

As app engine SDK is getting deprecated, I'm trying to switch to Google cloud SDK on a Java 8 webapp.

I'm getting the following error :

```
2019-10-04 11:08:54.226:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@618f627b{/,file:///foo/target/bar/,UNAVAILABLE}{/foo/target/bar}
MultiException[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to construct RemoteRpc due to unsupported url: <http://::1:8754/v1/projects/baz>, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException.ifExceptionThrow(MultiException.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:343)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

My appengine-web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app
xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

  <application>${appName}</application>
  <service>${appengine-service}</service>
  <version>${appengine.version}--${buildNumber}</version>

  <instance-class>${instance-class}</instance-class>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file"
      value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
  </system-properties>

  <ssl-enabled>true</ssl-enabled>
  <inbound-services>
    <service>mail</service>
  </inbound-services>

  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

</appengine-web-app>
```

My old plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.71</version>
  <configuration>
  <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
  <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My new one :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
  <projectId>bar</projectId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <deploy.promote>false</deploy.promote>
  <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
  <serviceAccountKeyFile>WEB-INF/ServiceAccountKey.json</serviceAccountKeyFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't know where this malformed URL (`http://::1:8754/...`) is coming from.

What did I miss ?

Comment: FWIW that looks like an IPv6 URL.

Comment: I noticed that :) Maybe that's the source of the problem, but I don't know where it comes from, so neither do I know how to set it up differently.

Comment: It seems that at some point in your application you are generating the URL from the server's IP and you are obtaining the network card URL